# Отсортировать многомерный массив PHP

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка, foreach

Есть массив:

```
array(191) {
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(3) "3"
    ["b"]=>
    string(53) "4"
    ["c"]=>
    string(31) "8"
  }
   [2]=>
    array(8) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(3) "5"
    ["b"]=>
    string(44) "666"
    ["c"]=>
    string(35) "69"
    ["d"]=>
    string(10) "777"
    }
}
```

вывожу требуемое циклом

```
foreach ($addressarray as $arr) {
        echo "
            раз: ".$arr['a']."<br />
            два: ".$arr['c']." <br />
            три: ".$arr['d'];
        }
```

Как отсортировать массив по значениям `["a"]`? То есть, чтобы на выходе было:

```
раз: 3
два: 4
три: 8

раз: 5
два: 666
три: 69
```

Про sort и asort читал, но не сортирует по вложенному массиву почему-то(

Пример разбираемого массива:

```
array(191) {
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["streetAddress"]=>
    string(53) "г.Жуковка, ул.Карла Маркса"
    ["region_name"]=>
    string(31) "Брянская область"
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(14) "Жуковка"
    ["workhours"]=>
    string(55) "пн-сб"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(11) "89123456789"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["streetAddress"]=>
    string(44) "г.Анапа, ул.Крымская"
    ["region_name"]=>
    string(35) "Краснодарский край"
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(10) "Анапа"
    ["workhours"]=>
    string(55) "пн-сб"
  }
```

Здесь надо отсортировать по region_name
Т.е. вывод адресов в алфавитном порядке

Comment: Попробуйте почитать про `array_multisort` - может сортировать и многомерные массивы..

Comment: Не дамп, а код. разные вещи. Не охото переписывать массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отсортировать с помощью **[uasort()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uasort.php)**:

```
$array = []; // Ваш массив
```

Пример для PHP >= 7:

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b){
    return $a["region_name"] <=> $b["region_name"];
});
```

Пример для PHP >= 5:

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a["region_name"] == $b["region_name"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["region_name"] < $b["region_name"]) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Просмотр массива после сортировки:

```
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '>' `
это видимо на Космический корабль `<=> ` ругается. Версия пхп 5.4 . Альтернативно это можно как-то сравнивать? @Эдуард

Comment: @theblackpost да, `<=>` поддерживается с php 7. Нужен пример для вашей версии? Или сами по ссылке его найдёте? )

Comment: если намекнёте - честь вам и хвала!) @Эдуард

Comment: @theblackpost я дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: Всё как часы! Спасибо, @Эдуард